# Is it possible to await a null literal?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

You can [await anything](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/) in C# 5+ so long as the type has a function called `.GetAwaiter()` that returns a special object or has a extension method that does the same.

Unity3d in its next major release is going to be supporting async/await. Currently in Unity3d you can `yield return null;` inside a coroutine to represent "Wait for next frame".

I was wondering if it is possible to craft a extension method that would allow you to do `await null;` to get the same behavior. There is no `System.Null` like there is a `System.Void`, so I could not think of what type to put in the extension method.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `await Task.Yield()`?

Comment: @spender Yes, the entire extension method would be `public static YieldAwaitable GetAwaiter(this ???? temp) { return Task.Yield(); }` I just don't know if there is something possible with the `????` part.

Comment: [Literal null has no type](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/25/what-is-the-type-of-the-null-literal/) according to the spec (since 3.0) anyway, so I don't think there can be anywhere to define an extension method.

Comment: @Blorgbeard post that as an answer and I would upvote it and likely accept it if no other answers came in.

Comment: On the flipside, you can cast a literal null to any reference type, so in theory you could choose any reference type you want.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on expert questioner. Just my thought `await Task<object>.CompletedTask()` or FromResult<T>

Comment: Well, posted, but hopefully a better answer comes along.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: It makes no sense to await a completed task whose value you already know; that's just boxing the value and immediately unboxing it; it does not even yield control back to the caller!  If you think that this operation makes sense in your workflow then you have a false belief about your workflow somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to define an extension method on a literal null, since a [literal `null` has no type](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/25/what-is-the-type-of-the-null-literal/):

> .. we realized that the null type was bizarre. It is a type with only one value — or is it? Is the value of a null nullable int really the same as the value of a null string? And don’t values of nullable value type already have a type, namely, the nullable value type?

And:

> Therefore we removed references to the useless “null type” in the C# 3.0 specification.

Comment: Though it is true that the null literal has no type, but rather is *compatible* with a variety of types, this fact does not necessarily *motivate* the design decision to not look up extension methods on null literals. Put another way: suppose I said, no, we were wrong, we should say that the null literal has the "null literal type".  Would that then motivate changing the design decision about extension methods? Probably not.

Comment: I guess that's true - I was using the lack of a null type as evidence that, given the current syntax for extension methods, there can be no way to express "this extension method applies to a literal null". But perhaps that's not exactly watertight reasoning.

Comment: We could easily have said that `static Whatever Foo(this object x) { ... } ... null.Foo();` is perfectly legal; `null` is convertible to `object`, which is all that is required. Now, you'd run into problems with `static Whatever Foo<T>(this T x)` because now `null.Foo()` cannot infer a type for T, but whatever, we already have that problem with `Foo(null);`.  No, `null.Foo()` was disallowed because it smells *awful*; if you're trying to put an extension method on a null literal, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: Yup, all true. I agree that it's smelly. I will resist the urge to edit my answer and quote that comment as my evidence instead of your blog post.

Answer (score 11):

You are right that yield and await are closely related. Both are points in a workflow where the current method is paused, control is returned to the caller, and the method resumes at an unspecified point in the future at the point where the yield / await happened.

But they are very different in terms of their action on their operands.  They are in fact *duals* of each other. A yield *provides* a new *value* when *demanded* by the code iterating the sequence.  An await *extracts* a value when it is *produced* by the asynchronously executing task.

Null is a perfectly valid value, so it makes sense for a yield to proffer it up to its caller. But null is not a valid *task*, and so it makes no sense for await to attempt to extract the *value* from the task.

> Currently in Unity3d you can yield return null; inside a coroutine to represent "Wait for next frame".

In an async-await asynchronous workflow the analog of `yield return null;` is just `return null;`. That means "end this portion of the asynchronous workflow by providing the null reference".  Why are you not simply returning null if you intend to produce a task whose result is null?

Let me put it another way that might be more clear.  Obviously this makes no sense:

```
foreach(var x in null)
   Console.WriteLine(x);
```

This is identically nonsensical:

```
var x = await null;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

These are the same thing logically. Foreach means "extract a value from the sequence as long as values are available", but null is not a sequence.  Similarly, "await" means "extract a value from the task as soon as a value is available", but null is not a task.

That's the key: the asynchronous analog of `await` is not `yield return`, it's `foreach`. That's the mechanism that extracts the `T` from the `IEnumerable<T>` or `Task<T>`.  The thing that puts the `T` *into* the monadic type is `yield return` for `IEnumerable<T>` and `return` for `Task<T>`.

Comment: To address your last paragraph it is because you will often have code after the yield return. For example if you want a loop to repeat once per frame till a condition is met you could have `while(_condition) { Foo(); yield return null; }` Unity3d abuses `IEnumerator` to create it's own async/await like system with Coroutines (This was created before async/await ever came out)

Comment: It could just as easily be `yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);` which would be the equivalent of `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: await and yield are not exactly duals because task and enumerable are not exactly duals. A task represents a single value obtained in the future; a sequence represents many values obtained on demand. The dual of task is actually func, and the dual of enumerable is observable. So if you want a *pushed sequence of values* then you don't want async await; you want `IObservable<T>`; you want reactive extensions.